# Generate a key column from nonfactor columns

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

Given a data frame of the form of

```r
       Key.1 Key.2      Value
1  5/25/2018   -10 0.53928999
2  5/25/2018   -10 0.23083204
3  5/25/2018   -10 0.33742676
4  5/25/2018     0 0.53479860
5  5/25/2018     0 0.27612761
6  5/25/2018     0 0.74993199
7  5/25/2018    10 0.01397069
8  5/25/2018    10 0.10553610
9  5/25/2018    10 0.66147883
10 1/17/2018   -10 0.14381738
11 1/17/2018   -10 0.52708544
12 1/17/2018   -10 0.75862925
13 1/17/2018     0 0.45954116
14 1/17/2018     0 0.68467543
15 1/17/2018     0 0.15865298
16 1/17/2018    10 0.01039363
17 1/17/2018    10 0.49886623
18 1/17/2018    10 0.98269967
19 5/25/2018    10 0.10553610
20 5/25/2018   -10 0.33742676
```

I need to generate a `Group` column from the interaction of `key.1` and `key.2` that would look something like

```r
       Key.1 Key.2      Value Group
1  5/25/2018   -10 0.53928999     1
2  5/25/2018   -10 0.23083204     1
3  5/25/2018   -10 0.33742676     1
4  5/25/2018     0 0.53479860     2
5  5/25/2018     0 0.27612761     2
6  5/25/2018     0 0.74993199     2
7  5/25/2018    10 0.01397069     3
8  5/25/2018    10 0.10553610     3
9  5/25/2018    10 0.66147883     3
10 1/17/2018   -10 0.14381738     4
11 1/17/2018   -10 0.52708544     4
12 1/17/2018   -10 0.75862925     4
13 1/17/2018     0 0.45954116     5
14 1/17/2018     0 0.68467543     5
15 1/17/2018     0 0.15865298     5
16 1/17/2018    10 0.01039363     6
17 1/17/2018    10 0.49886623     6
18 1/17/2018    10 0.98269967     6
19 5/25/2018    10 0.10553610     3
20 5/25/2018   -10 0.33742676     1
```

*note the last two rows*

where it is important that the value of `Group` is ascending down the data frame. I've managed to get the desired behavior with

```r
Data$Group          <-  interaction(paste(Data$Key.1,Data$Key.2),1)
levels(Data$Group)  <-  1:length(levels(Data$Group))
levels(Data$Group)  <-  unique(Data$Group)
```

however this feels exceedingly unintuitive and clunky.

**How could this be made to be both shorter and more intuitive?**

It is noted that there are no real limits on what `Key.1` or `Key.2` could be - the core behavior simply needs to be that `Group` is defined by the unique pair of `Key.1` and `Key.2`, and ascends down the table.

Comment: Is there some criteria in the `Key.2` or `Value` columns that need to be examined when determining what `Group` should be, or do you just need a repetitive sequence to do group assignment?

Comment: @mysteRious, no there is criteria for either the `Key.2` or `Value` columns that need to be considered during the grouping step.

Comment: `df$grp <- data.table::rleid(df$Key2)`

Comment: @PKumar that is extremely useful to know about, but unfortunately it does not quite capture the behavior that I was looking for (I've updated my generic test case to reflect that)

Comment: @TaylorScott, you can still use `rle`(run length encoding), give me some mins, are you also saying that your occurance of rows can come anywhere for eg you have added in the last shouldn't it be coming in the middle

Comment: @PKumar - sorry for the delay, I think that it would be most appropriate if the rows could come from anywhere

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea using factors:

With Base R:

```
df$Group = as.integer(factor(paste(df$Key.1, df$Key.2), 
                             levels = unique(paste(df$Key.1, df$Key.2))))
```

Or with `mutate` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df = mutate(df, Group = paste(Key.1, Key.2) %>% 
         factor(., levels = unique(.)) %>%
         as.integer())
```

**Result:**

```
       Key.1 Key.2      Value Group
1  5/25/2018   -10 0.53928999     1
2  5/25/2018   -10 0.23083204     1
3  5/25/2018   -10 0.33742676     1
4  5/25/2018     0 0.53479860     2
5  5/25/2018     0 0.27612761     2
6  5/25/2018     0 0.74993199     2
7  5/25/2018    10 0.01397069     3
8  5/25/2018    10 0.10553610     3
9  5/25/2018    10 0.66147883     3
10 1/17/2018   -10 0.14381738     4
11 1/17/2018   -10 0.52708544     4
12 1/17/2018   -10 0.75862925     4
13 1/17/2018     0 0.45954116     5
14 1/17/2018     0 0.68467543     5
15 1/17/2018     0 0.15865298     5
16 1/17/2018    10 0.01039363     6
17 1/17/2018    10 0.49886623     6
18 1/17/2018    10 0.98269967     6
19 5/25/2018    10 0.10553610     3
20 5/25/2018   -10 0.33742676     1
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(Key.1 = c("5/25/2018", "5/25/2018", "5/25/2018", 
"5/25/2018", "5/25/2018", "5/25/2018", "5/25/2018", "5/25/2018", 
"5/25/2018", "1/17/2018", "1/17/2018", "1/17/2018", "1/17/2018", 
"1/17/2018", "1/17/2018", "1/17/2018", "1/17/2018", "1/17/2018", 
"5/25/2018", "5/25/2018"), Key.2 = c(-10L, -10L, -10L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 10L, 10L, 10L, -10L, -10L, -10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, -10L), Value = c(0.53928999, 0.23083204, 0.33742676, 0.5347986, 
0.27612761, 0.74993199, 0.01397069, 0.1055361, 0.66147883, 0.14381738, 
0.52708544, 0.75862925, 0.45954116, 0.68467543, 0.15865298, 0.01039363, 
0.49886623, 0.98269967, 0.1055361, 0.33742676)), .Names = c("Key.1", 
"Key.2", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"))
```

Comment: @TaylorScott Sorry, I don't understand the question. "What do you mean by instantiate the `group` column with the mutate command?"

Comment: Uhhhh, the short version is I managed to copy and paste your command incorrectly - I missed the `df = ` and that made it only work in weird circumstances, but I realized that I am dumb, so don't worry about anything

Comment: @TaylorScott I am presenting two solutions here, one using only Base R commands, another using `mutate` from `dplyr`, so you should be able to copy and paste either one of those and get your `Group` column added to `df` no problem.

Comment: ahhh, it all makes sense now :D

Comment: @TaylorScott If you think that this answers your question, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `.GRP` symbol from `data.table` to assign unique number to groups. First group on `Key.1` and `Key.2` and then add new column with value `.GRP`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,Group:=.GRP, by=.(Key.1, Key.2)]  # Use of .GRP

#Check Result
df
#        Key.1 Key.2      Value Group
# 1: 5/25/2018   -10 0.53928999     1
# 2: 5/25/2018   -10 0.23083204     1
# 3: 5/25/2018   -10 0.33742676     1
# 4: 5/25/2018     0 0.53479860     2
# 5: 5/25/2018     0 0.27612761     2
# 6: 5/25/2018     0 0.74993199     2
# 7: 5/25/2018    10 0.01397069     3
# 8: 5/25/2018    10 0.10553610     3
# 9: 5/25/2018    10 0.66147883     3
# 10: 1/17/2018   -10 0.14381738     4
# 11: 1/17/2018   -10 0.52708544     4
# 12: 1/17/2018   -10 0.75862925     4
# 13: 1/17/2018     0 0.45954116     5
# 14: 1/17/2018     0 0.68467543     5
# 15: 1/17/2018     0 0.15865298     5
# 16: 1/17/2018    10 0.01039363     6
# 17: 1/17/2018    10 0.49886623     6
# 18: 1/17/2018    10 0.98269967     6
# 19: 5/25/2018    10 0.10553610     3
# 20: 5/25/2018   -10 0.33742676     1
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text =
"       Key.1 Key.2      Value
1  5/25/2018   -10 0.53928999
2  5/25/2018   -10 0.23083204
3  5/25/2018   -10 0.33742676
4  5/25/2018     0 0.53479860
5  5/25/2018     0 0.27612761
6  5/25/2018     0 0.74993199
7  5/25/2018    10 0.01397069
8  5/25/2018    10 0.10553610
9  5/25/2018    10 0.66147883
10 1/17/2018   -10 0.14381738
11 1/17/2018   -10 0.52708544
12 1/17/2018   -10 0.75862925
13 1/17/2018     0 0.45954116
14 1/17/2018     0 0.68467543
15 1/17/2018     0 0.15865298
16 1/17/2018    10 0.01039363
17 1/17/2018    10 0.49886623
18 1/17/2018    10 0.98269967
19 5/25/2018    10 0.10553610
20 5/25/2018   -10 0.33742676",
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```